# How to share files and folders on a forum so that anyone can download without having an Ubuntu One account?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sharing

I just began to discover Ubuntu One. I upload a video on my account, and put it in a folder.

I would like to know whether it is possible to share this folder or this file simply by giving the url in forum (in a message), so that anyone can download the file, with no need to have an Ubuntu One account.

(a bit like PhotoBucket, where you can share pictures and videos and folders to people with ou without PhotoBucket, and anyone can download them)

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

### On one.ubuntu.com

You can share a certain file by using the button **"Publish file"**. This option is revealed when you click the **"More"** button on the right.

[image]

Once clicked, it will provide an URL you can share with everybody. As far as I know this doesn't work for folders.

### On your machine

You can even share a certain file from within your UbuntuOne-Folder. Right-click it and choose **Ubuntu-One -> Publish**.

In the same right-click menu the same menu you can Copy the URL to clipboard (for me this point is always greyed out, whether the file is published or not. It works anyways.)

[image]

Comment: you have the option to rename the URL, which is recommended if you are sharing on a forum

Comment: @daithib8 : I can't find this option. Where is it? And why should the URL be renamed?

Comment: @serve.chilled You can use http://u1.to to create custom URLs to published files on Ubuntu One, but that is a third party service.

Comment: Thanks, @dobey. But: no legal information on the website, no whois-information - seems odd to me...

Comment: when you publish a file, you'll see a dialogue box to rename, otherwise you'll get fjidyjvddyjvddt.bin instead of goodies.deb

Comment: @daithib8 What are you talking about exactly? There is no such dialog box when publishing.

Comment: when you click publish there's a box with the public URL. If you save that URL with the browser it will give you the original filename, but if you save it with wget it won't.

Comment: I'm sorry it looks like you could change the URL but you can't.

Comment: sorry should have said input field rather than dialogue.

Comment: @seve.chilled u1.to is a private playground for two u1 developers. There is no whois data because the .to registrar is what it is.

Comment: All right, @RobertoAlsina. Seems legit ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage Ubuntu One for this usage on condition you are very careful, because there are a few quirks. A file name without an extension will be given a .bin extension. Likewise if any file is downloaded with wget. If you rename a file in Ubuntu one without unpublishing it first, then the recipient will receive a file with the original name. And the files often get saved and named as the last part of the url which can be a problem if you download many files and wish to be able to tell them apart. On  my stock Android browser this is the case, though not in Chromium on Ubuntu, where Nautilus is able to save the file under its original name. Minor niggles, to be sure, likely to be fixed in time.